# Generate access logs for different subdirectories in Apache

Tags: apache2

I have some sub-applications in my site, for example:

```
http://server/app/subapp1
http://server/app/subapp2
```

How can I generate different log files for each directory?

```
http://server/app/subapp1/log/access_log

http://server/app/subapp2/log/access_log
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/app/subapp1(/|$) subapp1
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/app/subapp2(/|$) subapp2

CustomLog /absolute/path/to/app/subapp1/log/access_log common env=subapp1
CustomLog /absolute/path/to/app/subapp2/log/access_log common env=subapp2
```

Comment: I've not had success with this answer ... my question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16154718/32836