# Apache server -- multiple directories, different error logs

Tags: apache2, error-log

I have two directories in /var/www (say, /var/www/app1 and /var/www/app2) whose error logs I want sent to different files.  Both are under the same domain, so I *think* that I can't put them under different virtual hosts.  So, for example, I would access them as:

http://localhost/app1

http://localhost/app2

I came across this page:

[Generate access logs for different subdirectories in Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460757/generate-access-logs-for-different-subdirectories-in-apache)

whose solution works perfectly for the access logs.  However, the "env" argument doesn't seem to work with the ErrorLog directive.

Before this "discovery", I was working on this, which seems wrong:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin ray@localhost

  DocumentRoot /var/www/app1

  <Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app1/error.log

  LogLevel warn

  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app1/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm somewhat lost about what I should be doing.  That is, if there is some way to get ErrorLog to work or if I should keep trying with configuring a virtual host for each directory.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: I have the same question, I'm looking for solution and I think creating a virtualhost by each folder and proxying internally maybe it works, it's only a theory :D for example: http://PublicDomain.com/folder shows content of http://folder.localhost

Comment: This is not OP's issue, but be aware - it can break when you have spaces in the path, if you do, you have to quote the path e.g. `/media/u/my super folder` => `"/media/u/my super folder"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why do you set `Directory` options for `/` in the `VirtualHost` context? Use `<Directory /var/www/app1>` instead of `<Directory />`

Due to the [Apache ErrorLog directive docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errorlog) its context is `server config, virtual host` - which means that it's only possible to define ErrorLog for the whole server or for a `VirtalHost`, not for a `Directory`. So if you want to send different logs to different files, try to use `SetEnvIf` to set an Env variable. Depeding on the directory where you are, it should be something like `SetEnvIf Request_URI ^\/a1\/ a1` and `SetEnvIf Request_URI ^\/a2\/ !a1`. Then write logs depending on the `a1` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my "Directory" mistake!  As for the ErrorLog, I did find out how environments work for separating out the access log.  But it doesn't seem to work for the error log.  Is my understanding correct?  (When I try, I get an error while Apache is parsing the configuration file.)  I guess you are right -- the error log is for a whole server or virtual host.  Based on the link that you sent, I suppose another option is to pipe each error log entry to a script...  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Yes, I've searched that too and seems like ErrorLog files can't be separated with SetEnvIf. You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Set custom ID for every Directory and you can separate logs by directories like this:

```
<Directory app1>
    SetEnv app1
</Directory>
<Directory app2>
    SetEnv app2
</Directory>
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site1.log combined env=app1
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site2.log combined env=app2
```

Comment: was `env=subwebsite1` intended to actually be `env=app1`? Otherwise, how "subwebsite1" is matched with "app1"?

Comment: @YakovL You're right, I edited my answer.

Comment: right, thanks. Do you know if something similar may be used with reverse proxy? (https://stackoverflow.com/q/68923480/3995261)

Comment: @YakovL Sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I did it, first create internal subdomains per folder and with proxypass pass the subdomain content.

Enable apache mods:

```
a2enmod authz_core dir proxy proxy_http
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       a.localhost
127.0.0.1       b.localhost
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost
        ServerAdmin fake@mail.com
        DocumentRoot "/dev/null"

        ProxyPass /a http://a.localhost/
        ProxyPassReverse /a http://a.localhost/
        ProxyPass /b http://b.localhost/
        ProxyPassReverse /b http://b.localhost/

        LogLevel debug

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/default-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/default-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/a.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName a.localhost
        ServerAdmin fake@mail.com
        DocumentRoot "/Publikoa/a"

        <Directory "/Publikoa/a">
                DirectoryIndex index.html
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        LogLevel debug

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/a-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/a-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/b.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName b.localhost
        ServerAdmin fake@mail.com
        DocumentRoot "/Publikoa/b"

        <Directory "Publikoa/b">
                DirectoryIndex index.html
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        LogLevel debug

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/b-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/b-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Enable sites:

```
a2ensite default a b
```

Restart apache:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```