#  Apache VirtualHost config for folder-separated sites within a single domain

Tags: apache

I would like to configure apache to allow per-site apache logging (access and error) and per-host php variables asignation. I have a **single domain** and all sites are accessed through it:

```
http://domain/site1
http://domain/site2
...
```

If I use Alias directive this way...

```
Alias /site1 /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/site1
Alias /site2 /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/site2
```

... I can't set neither custom logging by site nor php variables by site.

So I tried using *VirtualHost* directive but can't make it work. I tried using *domain/site1* in ServerAlias on each VirtualHost, it dosen't work. I also tried adding */site1* directly in  *VirtualHost* directive but I think it's not allowed. I tried a lot of conbinations but nothing works. I know VirtuaHosts are focused on using several domains but I suppose there is a solution for this scenario.

I also tried with *Directory* drective, but CustomLog is not allowed inside it. Any ideas?

Thanks for the help.

Aitor

Comment: One way is using subdomains instead of domain/folder, but I prefer the domain/folder way as I don't have to call my ISP to add the subdomain to the DNS each time I add a new site. But if there is no choice..

Comment: Following [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395043/apache-server-multiple-directories-different-error-logs) I think there is no way to achieve this.

Comment: It tells you the way to go, not this is impossible! Look around activating the httpd module which handle htaccess `SetEnvIf` directive and you could write conditions based on environment vars. If you are on a shared host, then consider change to a dedicated server... it's far flexible, as you can do that you need - but of course, you will do lots of things like using some time to learn what is security, and how to implement a webserver with enough security - which is another stuff.

Comment: But last comment on that post says "ErrorLog files can't be separated with SetEnvIf" So I think there is no other way than using subdomains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you insert the vhost definitions inside a `$HTTP_PATH/conf.d/vhost.conf` included by the main configuration file of Apache Web Server: `$HTTP_PATH/conf/httpd.conf` ?

Did you check the `php` integration with `httpd.conf` ? 
Loading php modules, etc.

Did you check the `php.ini` file regarding your application `.htaccess` & `php` requirements ?

Making an alias is really a bad way to do, unless the site could be accessed for any hostnames on your server... but don't forget that it will certainly put down your score on any search engines.

Please give us more information, with a substract of /var/log/httpd/error_log.

You can get it with `tail -f /path/to/error/log`

**Added:**
You can look at the httpd module `mod_log_config`.
Default log line is formatted like below:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

Change it to:

```
LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

Where %v will insert the name of the virtualhost inside your logs.
These name will be displayed & filtered by the parser indicated below.

And use the script distributed with apache web server to get virtualhosts separated logs files: the famous `/src/support/split-logfile.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# ====================================================================
# Copyright (c) 1995-1998 The Apache Group.  All rights reserved.
#
# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
# modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
# are met:
#
# 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
#    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer. 
#
# 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
#    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
#    the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
#    distribution.
#
# 3. All advertising materials mentioning features or use of this
#    software must display the following acknowledgment:
#    "This product includes software developed by the Apache Group
#    for use in the Apache HTTP server project (http://www.apache.org/)."
#
# 4. The names "Apache Server" and "Apache Group" must not be used to
#    endorse or promote products derived from this software without
#    prior written permission.  For permission please contact
#    Apache@Apache.Org.
#
# 5. Products derived from this software may not be called "Apache"
#    nor may "Apache" appear in their names without prior written
#    permission of the Apache Group.
#
# 6. Redistributions of any form whatsoever must retain the following
#    acknowledgment:
#    "This product includes software developed by the Apache Group
#    for use in the Apache HTTP server project (http://www.apache.org/)."
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE APACHE GROUP ``AS IS'' AND ANY
# EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
# IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
# PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE APACHE GROUP OR
# ITS CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
# SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT
# NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
# LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
# HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT,
# STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
# ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED
# OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
# ====================================================================
#
# This software consists of voluntary contributions made by many
# individuals on behalf of the Apache Group and was originally based
# on public domain software written at the National Center for
# Supercomputing Applications, University of Illinois, Urbana-Champaign.
# For more information on the Apache Group and the Apache HTTP server
# project, please see <http://www.apache.org/>.
#

#
# This script will take a combined Web server access
# log file and break its contents into separate files.
# It assumes that the first field of each line is the
# virtual host identity (put there by "%v"), and that
# the logfiles should be named that+".log" in the current
# directory.
#
# The combined log file is read from stdin. Records read
# will be appended to any existing log files.
#
%is_open = ();

while ($log_line = <STDIN>) {
    #
    # Get the first token from the log record; it's the
    # identity of the virtual host to which the record
    # applies.
    #
    ($vhost) = split (/\s/, $log_line);
    #
    # Normalize the virtual host name to all lowercase.
    # If it's blank, the request was handled by the default
    # server, so supply a default name.  This shouldn't
    # happen, but caution rocks.
    #
    $vhost = lc ($vhost) or "access";
    #
    # If the log file for this virtual host isn't opened
    # yet, do it now.
    #
    if (! $is_open{$vhost}) {
        open $vhost, ">>${vhost}.log"
            or die ("Can't open ${vhost}.log");
        $is_open{$vhost} = 1;
    }
    #
    # Strip off the first token (which may be null in the
    # case of the default server), and write the edited
    # record to the current log file.
    #
    $log_line =~ s/^\S*\s+//;
    printf $vhost "%s", $log_line;
}
exit 0;
```

And you can check with the following [logcron](http://slacksite.com/apache/scripts/logcron) script if these one is not enough. You can follow the text in [these article](http://slacksite.com/apache/logging.php).

Comment: Yes to all questions. There are no noteworthy errors in error_log. I know pretty well what I am doing, the thing is I don't know how to create a virtualhost like configuration with all the advantages it has (custom logs, custom php varaibles values) with a single domain. With .htaccess I could set php variables, yes, but no customlog directive because logging system must be enabled before apache reaches the directory where .htaccess is. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: So you can do what you need with the stuff added to my response.

Comment: A combination of your solution for logs and per-folder .htaccess for setting independent PHP variables could solve the problem. But my conclusion here is that it's much better to use subdomains instead of my approach. Thanks.

Comment: Subdomains have my preference too.
But if you can't do with, then my response will do the job ;)