# 2CRM environment on 1 server needs separate logging

Tags: apache, logging, error-logging

We have a **centOS** server running with **apache** and two environments on it. One for **dev** and one for **test**.

The problem is, that both environments are logging in the same file.

Do you have any idea how to set them up to log into separate `error_log` files???

Comment: Hello Rambo, welcome to StackOverflow. :-) How did you seperate the two environments? Did you do it by routing/different folders? Please specify that aspect in your question :-) In addition, did you already try to configure apache into separating the error logs and if so, what did you already try?

Comment: Hi, I havent tried anything yet. the 2 environments are under /var/www/html/xxx_dev and xxx_test. So 2 folders are under html. I found httpd.conf where it says ErrorLog "logs/error_log". I havent tried coinfigureing apache at all. Im pretty new on this field..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache server -- multiple directories, different error logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395043/apache-server-multiple-directories-different-error-logs)

Comment: Thanks. Ill give it a try.