# Two sites with two different log files - SSL Apache2 Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ssl, ubuntu-16.04, virtualhost, lets-encrypt

I have two websites in the same web server (Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS - Apache/2.4.18). Everything works well when I try to access to both websites using HTTP (port 80). This is the vhosts.conf file content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site1_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site1_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site2
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site2_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site2_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

So, both sites are accessible through "mydomain.com/site1" and "mydomain.com/site2". I have installed a Let's Encrypt certificate and, to make it works, I have configured a virtual host like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site_access.log combined
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I can access both site using SSL (port 443) successfully but I can't use different log files for different sites. I have tried something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.com/site1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site1_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site1_access.log combined
    Alias /site1 /var/www/html/site1
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.com/site2
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site2_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site2_access.log combined
    Alias /site2 /var/www/html/site2
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't work. How can I distinguish between two sites in order to have two different log files?

Comment: Step 1: Go inform yourself what a server name is. Hint: `mydomain.com/site1` isn’t one.

Comment: This was my last test. I understand that in both cases, ServerName should be the same, but then, I don't know how to distinguis between two sites.

Comment: _“How can I distinguish between two sites in order to have two different log files?”_ - you can’t, not with only one domain/virtual host, because CustomLog only works in the contexts of server config or virtual host. You want to start by setting this up as `mydomain1.com` and `mydomain2.com`, so that you actually have something that could technically by called “two different sites” to begin with.

Comment: If I use two different ServerNames, then the problem is that one isn't real, so in the error log I see something like:
[ssl:warn] [pid 4017] AH01909: mydomain2.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: Well then get a certificate that covers both domains, or configure one for each domain individually.

Comment: So then, if I understand it right, it isn't possible to have something like "https://example.com/site1" and "https://example.com/site2" and to have different log files for different sites, right?

Comment: Check if this works for you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460757/generate-access-logs-for-different-subdirectories-in-apache

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the link proposed by CBroe, I have found the solution by using the SetEnvIf directive. The final working virtual host configuration looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/site1(/|$) site1
    SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/site2(/|$) site2
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site1_access.log combined env=site1
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site2_access.log combined env=site2
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site_error.log
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```